# Scenarios for differences between UICulture and Culture

Tags: .net, asp.net, internationalization, localization

In .NET there are two "culture" values, UICulture and Culture. The first one is for localized texts on the UI, while the latter sets the culture for date and number formats.

I can't come up with any reason or scenario for those two values to be different. Is there some reason to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some cases they can be different for example if you live in a foreign country and you want to change the UI language to a language that you are familiarly with, but you still want to use the date and number formats of that foreign country like:

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="en-US" />
```

The other way around if you are doing business with an other country that your own, you probably want to use you own language, but change the date and number format.

And most of the time they are diffrent because you use the main culture (without the subculture) for the UI, `en` instead of `en-US`.

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you, didn't think about that.